# Another issue with to_number(). I simply do not understand it

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have a master table (hereafter called SURVEY) and a detail table (hereafter called ANSWERS.)  Unsurprisingly, ANSWERS has answers to SURVEY questions.  ANSWERS has a VARCHAR2 column named TEXT.  Some ANSWERS.TEXT values are truly text but some are actually numerics.  Fortunately, I always know which rows contain text and which contain numbers-as-text.

**This is the way it is.  I can't change this.**

Back in the day, when certain ANSWERS rows were saved, their TEXT values were cherry-picked and put into the SURVEY table in properly typed columns. A trivial one-table select would fetch SURVEYs and the special values.

But now, with the addition of a new application, we've removed the special columns.  Instead, we now have to fetch the appropriate ANSWERS rows' TEXT values instead.

I have created a query that simulates the old trivial select statement.  It works great... mostly.

Here's a snippet:

```
select survey.*, 
       j2.overall_score
  from survey,
       (select to_number(trim(ANSWER.text)) overall_score, 
               survey.id survey_id 
          from ANSWER, 
               [edited - more SQL that gets the 'score' row from ANSWERS]) j2      
 where
   survey.id=j2.survey_id
   and overall_score > 70
```

You might note the j2.  In the real query, there are six such columns, j1 through j6.  When I run the query, it looks *just* like the old query.  You can't tell it's really being assembled from a master/detail.  That's a relief!

My problem, however, is that the 'overall_score > 70' phrase causes a '1722 invalid number' error.  Oracle is as happy as a clam when I don't include the phrase, so all the output is passing through j2's to_number() function and looks good. But if I add the conditional, I fail.

The 'overall_score' part of the where clause is being added dynamically based upon search criteria entered from a web page.

I need some *fu* that tells Oracle I really do know what I'm doing, please do it.  If there is non-numeric data, ok, let j2's to_number() fail. Cool.  But otherwise, just do it.

Any wise words? I'm a contractor and time is nearly up.  This is a new requirement :-/

Comment: Have you looked at what `j2` is returning, separately from the final query?  I find it hard to believe that you're getting an invalid number error on the outer query--I'd expect the `TO_NUMBER` conversion to trigger the error.

Comment: If I remove the '> 70' conditional, the query returns rows. When I add the conditional, I get '1722 invalid number' sadness.

Comment: oops hit return instead of newline.  When I run the j2 subquery alone, it returns valid rows without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We created a special version of to_number which internally catches the '1722 invalid number' exception and returns 0 instead of. Replacing to_number with this new function in th sql eliminated this problem for us.

Comment: I'm dead in the water now.  I'll try it but I suppose if my SQL is valid then no crud will get through.

Comment: This allows my query to run.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I think that the optimizer is probably merging the inline view with the rest of the query, which means that the condition `overall_score > 70` may be evaluated for rows that don't match the rest of the view's predicates, thereby hitting rows that don't contain numeric values in `text`.

If that's what happening, you should be able to prevent it by adding a hint in the first line of the query:

```
select /*+ NO_MERGE(j2) */ ...
```

Alternatively, it could be pushing the predicate into the view, in which case you would need the NO_PUSH_PRED hint.  If you can generate an execution plan for the query, it will probably show what the exact issue is.

Comment: Will do.  The DBA is creating me a plan table now :-D

Comment: Explain output is too long to post.  I'm using oracle's UTLXPLS to see the result.  What do you use?

Comment: I created a view of the unqualified query.  Then I select from the view with the overall_score > 70.  This also failed.  That's curious unless Oracle's optimizer is smart enough to optimize views' internals when used in a select.  I checked the data again, the column in question is always a numeric-as-text for the 'overall score' row.

Comment: Added NO_MERGE(j2) and NO_PUSH_PRED(j2) (and in fact for all j1..6) and got the same result.

Comment: Oracle will happily optimise a view's internals when used in a larger select. It just squishes the full SQL together as if the view wasn't there - the view just makes things easier for the person putting together the SQL.

Comment: I bet a materialzed view would have done the trick.  I don't have the rights to create one to try it, however.